# Method FillContainsWithDetail not working as expected

Tags: c#, wpf, intersection

The method FillContainsWithDetail is expected to return me Empty when the first shape is not touching another and it is, it must return FullyContains. But when I was making a few test I saw that was not what it returns...

That's the method which return if the shape is touched or not.

```
public string CheckIfInside(Shape shpPlayer, Shape shpObject)
{
    Geometry geo1 = shpPlayer.RenderedGeometry;
    Geometry geo2 = shpObject.RenderedGeometry;

    string s = geo1.FillContainsWithDetail(geo2).ToString();
    return s;
}
```

Returns of the method above

```
    [0] "Empty" 
    [1] "Empty" 
    [2] "Intersects"    
    [3] "Intersects"    
    [4] "Intersects"    
    [5] "Empty" 
    [6] "Empty" 
    [7] "Intersects"    
    [8] "Intersects"    
    [9] "FullyInside"   
    [10]    "Empty" 
    [11]    "Empty" 
    [12]    "FullyInside"   
    [13]    "Empty" 
    [14]    "Empty" 
    [15]    "FullyInside"   
    [16]    "Empty" 
    [17]    "Empty" 
    [18]    "FullyInside"   
    [19]    "Empty" 
    [20]    "Empty" 
    [21]    "FullyInside"   
    [22]    "Empty" 
    [23]    "Empty" 
    [24]    "FullyInside"   
    [25]    "Empty" 
    [26]    "Empty" 
    [27]    "FullyInside"   
    [28]    "Empty" 
    [29]    "Empty" 
    [30]    "FullyInside"   
    [31]    "Empty" 
    [32]    "Empty" 
    [33]    "FullyInside"   
    [34]    "Empty" 
    [35]    "Empty" 
    [36]    "FullyInside"   
    [37]    "Empty" 
    [38]    "Empty" 
    [39]    "FullyInside"   
    [40]    "Empty" 
    [41]    "Empty" 
    [42]    "FullyInside"   
    [43]    "Empty" 
    [44]    "Empty" 
    [45]    "FullyInside"   
    [46]    "Empty" 
    [47]    "Empty" 
    [48]    "FullyInside"   
    [49]    "Empty" 
    [50]    "Empty"
```

[image: Screenshot of the game] (The player [shpPlayer / geo1] is the little cube in red and the shapes are the trees and the lakes)

Thank you for your help :D

Comment: Please host your images here. It's easily done in the question editor. I have no idea what noelshack is and I'm not going to click on it to find out. Secondly, I can't be sure what "returns of the method above" means, but if it's a screenshot of code or of an error message, paste it as plain text into your question.

Comment: I think we can see it more clearly when it's a screenshot and thanks for your answer.

Comment: I'm sorry but I was thinking in another way

Comment: So you called the method 51 times with the objects located in different places, I guess, and you got different results. Not knowing the inputs you gave it, nobody can tell you anything useful. Your best course would be to read the documentation on the method you're calling, *and* of `Geometry`, and then figure out exactly what information you're giving it. I suspect that when the method says they intersect, they're intersecting. Are you saying you think they aren't? What makes you so sure?

Comment: I've spent a few decades staring angrily at the screen and muttering curses, and based on that experience, I suspect there's something here that isn't what you think it is, or doesn't mean what you think it does. You'll have to identify your assumptions and examine them one by one.

Comment: I'm testing every shape in my grid to know if the player (the red cube) is inside (of the current shape in the loop) or not.
foreach (Shape shp in game.Shapes)
{
        game.CheckIfInside(player.CubePlayer, shp);
}

Comment: OK, but I have no idea a) which "Empty" corresponds to which shape, b) what the player's Geometry is, or c) what any of the shapes' Geometries are.

Comment: I neither. But I know that is must be always "Empty" because the player is not touching any shape.

Comment: Therefore, one of your assumptions is wrong. How are the shapes' positions defined? Is it in effect assuming that everything is at 0,0?

Comment: The positions of the shapes are defined randomly and the position of the player is defined at 0, 0 yes.

Comment: Ok I find an error into my code... I have not updated the position of the player in my list... I don't know if it is that but I think that can resolve some problems

Comment: Next time (or this time, if that isn't the answer) make a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's impossible to guess what errors may be in code I've never seen.

Comment: Ok sorry and btw thank's for your help.

Comment: @Greenkiller As a general hint you can usually assume that the framework just works correctly and your code has a bug. Check your code twice before asking things like this. You should probably delete the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the answer finally. The problem was that I was using RenderedGeometry to get the Geometry but it does not return really a Geomerty... At least not as I want. So I made my own method to do it if this can help you.

```
private Geometry ConvertToGeometry(Shape s)
    {
        if (s.GetType() == new Rectangle().GetType())
        {
            return new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(new Point(s.Margin.Left, s.Margin.Top), new Point(s.Margin.Left + s.Width, s.Margin.Top + s.Height)));
        }
        if (s.GetType() == new Ellipse().GetType())
        {
            return new EllipseGeometry(new Point(s.Width / 2 + s.Margin.Left, s.Height / 2 + s.Margin.Top), s.Width / 2, s.Height / 2);
        }
        if (s.GetType() == new Polygon().GetType())
        {
            Polygon p = (Polygon)s;
            List<PathSegment> ps = new List<PathSegment>();
            for (int i = 1; i < p.Points.Count; i++)
            {
                ps.Add(new LineSegment(p.Points[i], true));
            }
            PathGeometry pg = new PathGeometry(new PathFigure[] { new PathFigure(p.Points[0], ps, true) });
            return pg;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This method work for Rectangle, Ellipse and Polygon from Shapes.
Thank to everyone who helped me :D

Comment: You can do `s is Ellipse` instead of that... thing you have. Look up the typeof operator too. Looks like the position was part of the problem? Might be faster to offset the player instead though.